# What is meant by "don't run processes as root in a chroot environmentl"

Tags: linux, unix, root, chroot, chroot-jail

I read several articles that say one should avoid running processes as root in a chroot environment since it allows the process to escape.

But how should I do that? Chroot can only be evoked by root, so it is impossible to run a processes in a chroot environment without root privileges, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you need to invoke `chroot` as root,
the `chroot` option [--userspec=USER:GROUP](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chroot-invocation.html) will run the command under
the non-root UID/GID.

A more recent way to `chroot` without root-permissions is with
the [unshare command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html)
provided by [mount namespaces](https://lwn.net/Articles/689856/).

For more information, see the post
[How to run a command in a chroot jail not as root and without sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737008/how-to-run-a-command-in-a-chroot-jail-not-as-root-and-without-sudo)